# Como unificar namespaces redundantes de um XML?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, namespace

Tenho o seguinte XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DataTable>
  <Columns>
    <DataColumn xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <ColumnName>NomeColuna1</ColumnName>
      <TypeName>System.String</TypeName>
    </DataColumn>
    <DataColumn xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <ColumnName>NomeColuna2</ColumnName>
      <TypeName>System.String</TypeName>
    </DataColumn>
    <DataColumn xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <ColumnName>NomeColuna3</ColumnName>
      <TypeName>System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]</TypeName>
    </DataColumn>
    <DataColumn xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <ColumnName>NomeColunaN</ColumnName>
      <TypeName>System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]</TypeName>
    </DataColumn>
  </Columns>
</DataTable>
```

Cada tag `<DataColumn>` foi gerada previamente a partir de um processo individual de serialização.

Ao final, todas estas tags são envelopadas na tag de agrupamento `<Columns>` durante a gravação efetiva do XML (utilizo, neste caso, um [`XmlTextWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

Como não controlo a serialização de cada tag `<DataColumn>`, o namespace `xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` será declarado para cada uma delas.

Existe uma forma simples de, ao término da construção do XML final, efetuar uma limpeza para reduzir redundâncias? O resultado que eu espero seria:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DataTable xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Columns>
    <DataColumn>
      <ColumnName>NomeColuna1</ColumnName>
      <TypeName>System.String</TypeName>
    </DataColumn>
    <DataColumn>
      <ColumnName>NomeColuna2</ColumnName>
      <TypeName>System.String</TypeName>
    </DataColumn>
    <DataColumn>
      <ColumnName>NomeColuna3</ColumnName>
      <TypeName>System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]</TypeName>
    </DataColumn>
    <DataColumn>
      <ColumnName>NomeColunaN</ColumnName>
      <TypeName>System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]</TypeName>
    </DataColumn>
  </Columns>
</DataTable>
```

Comment: O curioso é que esse namespace nem é usado no documento. Você pode postar o código que gera o XML relevante?

Comment: Este namespace é gerado automaticamente pelo .NET quando utilizada serialização por `DataContract`; Se utilizada serialização `XMLSerializer`, isto também ocorrerá, porém com o alias `xmlns:xsi=...`

Comment: Não seria algo como '<i:DataColumn [...] />'?

Comment: @Butzke: Neste caso, *Jordão* tem razão - não haveria necessidade deste namespace. Como não tenho controle sobre a geração dele e, pelo que pesquisei no SO gringo, dá um pouco de trabalho removê-lo. Ao menos, gostaria de saber se existe algum método em alguma classe do .NET (ou se alguém construiu algo) que realizasse uma "limpa" no XML.
Como pretendo salvar esse XML no banco, me importaria com um XML mais enxuto.

Comment: Como vc escreve as tags no XmlTextWriter? Com WriteRaw?

Comment: @Jordão: Exato, isso mesmo!

Comment: Notar que no exemplo de resultado esperado você não eliminou uma redundância no local esperado, você realmente mudou o namespace de lugar. Imagine se dentro do <Columns> ou do <Datatable> fosse adicionado um outro elemento que não DataColumn, ele assumiria o namespace mencionado, o que poderia não ser correto. (talvez pro seu uso específico sim, mas não é uma coisa que uma aplicação pudesse simplesmente "adivinhar" como otimizar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bom, supondo que você escreve cada fragmento de XML de uma `string` para um `XmlTextWriter`, uma forma de remover o *namespace* indesejado, que não terá nenhum impacto na validade do XML final, é de ler o fragmento de XML e processá-lo de acordo:

```c#
public static void WriteXml(XmlTextWriter writer, string xml) {
    var reader = XmlTextReader.Create(new StringReader(xml));
    while (reader.Read()) {
        WriteNode(writer, reader);
    }
}

private static void WriteNode(XmlTextWriter writer, XmlReader reader) {
    switch (reader.NodeType) {
        case XmlNodeType.Element: WriteStartElement(writer, reader); break;
        case XmlNodeType.EndElement: writer.WriteEndElement(); break;
        case XmlNodeType.Text: writer.WriteString(reader.Value); break;
        case XmlNodeType.Whitespace: writer.WriteWhitespace(reader.Value); break;
    }
}

private static void WriteStartElement(XmlTextWriter writer, XmlReader reader) {
    writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Prefix, reader.LocalName, reader.NamespaceURI);
    WriteAttributes(writer, reader);
}

private static void WriteAttributes(XmlTextWriter writer, XmlReader reader) {
    for (int i = 0; i < reader.AttributeCount; i++) {
        reader.MoveToAttribute(i);
        if (reader.Value == "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance") continue;
        writer.WriteAttributeString(reader.Prefix, reader.LocalName, reader.NamespaceURI, reader.Value);
    }
    reader.MoveToElement();
}
```

Note que esse código pode não funcionar com outros XMLs. Você passa cada fragmento no parâmetro `xml` do método `WriteXml` em um loop, sempre passando o mesmo `writer`. Cada fragmento se parece com:

```xml
<DataColumn xmlns:i='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>
  <ColumnName>NomeColuna1</ColumnName>
  <TypeName>System.String</TypeName>
</DataColumn>
```

Se isso não funciona com o código que você tem, por favor publique as partes relevantes do código que escrevem os fragmentos XML no `XmlTextWriter`.

Comment: Obrigado! Seu código faz sentido (+1) e será útil para um teste (que infelizmente não poderei rodar agora).
Me veio à mente agora (que também irei pesquisar) se existe um processo de c14n que posso aplicar no XML para resolver esse problema... Grato! :)

Comment: Sim existe: olhe a classe [`XmlDsigC14NTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.xmldsigc14ntransform(v=vs.110).aspx). Eu tentei usá-la, mas não consegui canonicalizar o XML :-(

Comment: Acho que essa classe só funciona no contexto de assinar um XML. Mas se conseguir canonicalizar um XML, por favor publique como uma resposta.

Comment: Obrigado mais uma vez. Tentarei e se conseguir posto o código aqui!